# Parsing data from text file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a text file that has content like this:

```
******** ENTRY 01 ********
ID:                  01
Data1:               0.1834869385E-002
Data2:              10.9598489301
Data3:              -0.1091356549E+001
Data4:                715
```

And then an empty line, and repeats more similar blocks, all of them with the same data fields.

I am porting to Python a C++ code, and a certain part gets the file line by line, detects the text title and then detect each field text to extract the data. This doesn't look like a smart code at all, and I think Python must have some library to parse data like this easily. After all, it almost look like a CSV!

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very far from CSV, actually.

You can use the file as an iterator; the following generator function yields complete sections:

```
def load_sections(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        line = ''
        while True:
            while not line.startswith('****'): 
                line = next(infile)  # raises StopIteration, ending the generator
                continue  # find next entry

            entry = {}
            for line in infile:
                line = line.strip()
                if not line: break

                key, value = map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
                entry[key] = value

            yield entry
```

This treats the file as an iterator, meaning that any looping advances the file to the next line. The outer loop only serves to move from section to section; the inner `while` and `for` loops do all the real work; first skip lines until a `****` header section is found (otherwise discarded), then loop over all non-empty lines to create a section.

Use the function in a loop:

```
for section in load_sections(filename):
    print section
```

Repeating your sample data in a text file results in:

```
>>> for section in load_sections('/tmp/test.txt'):
...     print section
... 
{'Data4': '715', 'Data1': '0.1834869385E-002', 'ID': '01', 'Data3': '-0.1091356549E+001', 'Data2': '10.9598489301'}
{'Data4': '715', 'Data1': '0.1834869385E-002', 'ID': '01', 'Data3': '-0.1091356549E+001', 'Data2': '10.9598489301'}
{'Data4': '715', 'Data1': '0.1834869385E-002', 'ID': '01', 'Data3': '-0.1091356549E+001', 'Data2': '10.9598489301'}
```

You can add some data converters to that if you want to; a mapping of key to callable would do:

```
converters = {'ID': int, 'Data1': float, 'Data2': float, 'Data3': float, 'Data4': int}
```

then in the generator function, instead of `entry[key] = value` do `entry[key] = converters.get(key, lambda v: v)(value)`.

Answer (score 4):

my_file:

```
******** ENTRY 01 ********
ID:                  01
Data1:               0.1834869385E-002
Data2:              10.9598489301
Data3:              -0.1091356549E+001
Data4:                715

ID:                  02
Data1:               0.18348674325E-012
Data2:              10.9598489301
Data3:              0.0
Data4:                5748

ID:                  03
Data1:               20.1834869385E-002
Data2:              10.954576354
Data3:              10.13476858762435E+001
Data4:                7456
```

Python script:

```
import re

with open('my_file', 'r') as f:
    data  = list()
    group = dict()
    for key, value in re.findall(r'(.*):\s*([\dE+-.]+)', f.read()):
        if key in group:
            data.append(group)
            group = dict()
        group[key] = value
    data.append(group)

print data
```

Printed output:

```
[
    {
        'Data4': '715',
        'Data1': '0.1834869385E-002',
        'ID': '01',
        'Data3': '-0.1091356549E+001',
        'Data2': '10.9598489301'
    },
    {
        'Data4': '5748',
        'Data1': '0.18348674325E-012',
        'ID': '02',
        'Data3': '0.0',
        'Data2': '10.9598489301'
    },
    {
        'Data4': '7456',
        'Data1': '20.1834869385E-002',
        'ID': '03',
        'Data3': '10.13476858762435E+001',
        'Data2': '10.954576354'
    }
]
```

Comment: I think this does not group into records.

Comment: Very fancy! But I have allergy to RegEx, so I prefer Martijn solution due to my limitations. Thanks for your great answer anyway!

Comment: @RomanRdgz Thank you! Actually I'm in love with regular expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach could be

```
all_objects = []

with open("datafile") as f:
    for L in f:
        if L[:3] == "***":
            # Line starts with asterisks, create a new object
            all_objects.append({})
        elif ":" in L:
            # Line is a key/value field, update current object
            k, v = map(str.strip, L.split(":", 1))
            all_objects[-1][k] = v
```

Comment: It is better and safer to use `with open('datafile') as f:` than simply `open('datafile')`, because it will automatically `close` the file, even exception is occurred.

Comment: @PeterVaro: better and safer and longer and (IMO) a bit uglier. Fixed anyway as apparently Python is going there