# Splitting a list into a file without duplicates

Tags: python, list, iteration

Large data file like this:

```
133621    652.4   496.7  1993.0 ...
END       SAMPLES EVENTS  RES  271.0     2215.0 ...
ESACC     935.6   270.6  2215.0 ...
115133    936.7   270.3  2216.0 ...
115137    936.4   270.4  2219.0 ...
115141    936.1   271.0  2220.0 ...
ESACC L   114837    115141  308   938.5   273.3    2200
115145    936.3   271.8  2220.0 ...
END 115146  SAMPLES EVENTS  RES   44.11   44.09
SFIX L   133477
133477    650.8   500.0  2013.0 ...
133481    650.2   499.9  2012.0 ...
ESACC     650.0   500.0  2009.0 ...
```

Want to grab only the ESACC data into trials. When END appears, preceding ESACC data is aggregated into a trial. Right now, I can get the first chunk of ESACC data into a file but because the loop restarts from the beginning of the data, it keeps grabbing only the first chunk so I have 80 trials with the exact same data.

```
for i in range(num_trials):
   with open(fid) as testFile:
       for tline in testFile:

           if 'END' in tline:
               fid_temp_start.close()
               fid_temp_end.close()   #Close the files
               break

           elif 'ESACC' in tline:

               tline_snap = tline.split()
               sac_x_start = tline_snap[4]
               sac_y_start = tline_snap[5

               sac_x_end = tline_snap[7]
               sac_y_end = tline_snap[8]
```

My question: How to iterate to the next chunk of data without grabbing the previous chunks?

Comment: You need to keep track where your reading pointer is, using a concept of "current" and "previous" data sets.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105456/parsing-data-from-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your code something like this:

```py
def data_parse(filepath): #Make it a function
    try:
        with open(filepath) as testFile:
            tline = '' #Initialize tline
            while True: #Switch to an infinite while loop (I'll explain why)
                while 'ESACC' not in tline: #Skip lines until one containing 'ESACC' is found
                    tline = next(testFile)  #(since it seems like you're doing that anyway)

                tline_snap = tline.split()
                trial = [tline_snap[4],'','',''] #Initialize list and assign first value
                trial[1] = tline_snap[5]

                trial[2] = tline_snap[7]
                trial[3] = tline_snap[8]

                while 'END' not in tline:  #Again, seems like you're skipping lines
                    tline = next(testFile) #so I'll do the same

                yield trial #Output list, save function state

    except StopIteration:
        fid_temp_start.close() #I don't know where these enter the picture
        fid_temp_end.close()   #but you closed them so I will too
        testfile.close()

#Now, initialize a new list and call the function:
trials = list()
for trial in data_parse(fid);
    trials.append(trial) #Creates a list of lists
```

What this creates is a generator function. By using `yield` instead of `return`, the function returns a value AND saves its state. The next time you call the function (as you will do repeatedly in the `for` loop at the end), it picks up where it left off. It starts at the line after the most recently executed `yield` statement (which in this case restarts the `while` loop) and, importantly, it remembers the values of any variables (like the value of tline and the point it stopped at in the data file).

When you reach the end of the file (and have thus recorded all of your trials), the next execution of `tline = next(testFile)` raises a StopIteration error. The `try - except` structure catches that error and uses it to exit the `while` loop and close your files. This is why we use an infinite loop; we want to continue looping until that error forces us out.

At the end of the whole thing, your data is stored in `trials` as a list of lists, where each item equals `[sac_x_start, sac_y_start, sac_x_end, sac_y_end]`, as you defined them in your code, for one trial.

Note: it does seem to me like your code is skipping lines entirely when they don't contain ESACC or END. I've replicated that, but I'm not sure if that's what you want. If you want to get the lines in between, you can rewrite this fairly simply by adding to the `'END'` loop as below:

```py
while 'END' not in tline:
    tline = next(testFile)
    #(put assignment operations to be applied to each line here)
```

Of course, you'll have to adjust the variable you're using to store this data accordingly.

Edit: Oh dear lord, I just now noticed how old this question is.